# Proving this series is convergent almost everywhere

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\},\{r_n\}$ be two sequences of real numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|<\infty$. Prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{|x-r_n|}}$$ converges absolutely almost everywhere for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

http://www.math.washington.edu/~solomyak/TEACH/524/13/prac2.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have to fix $x$, we can only make one term of the sequence $\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{|x-r_n|}}$ diverge by letting $x\to r_n$ for some $n$, but the point $x$ is set set of measure zero, so it converges almost everywhere.

Another case would be for $r_n\to r$ let $x=r$ and the series diverges, but again, this is only one point, so we have measure zero again, so we have almost everywhere again.